# redux saga while true continuous calls

Tags: websocket, redux-saga

I have tried to implement WebSocket with redux-saga;

I have found this implementation:

```
function* flow() {
  while (true) {
    let { payload } = yield take(`${login}`);
    const socket = yield call(connect);
    socket.emit('login', { username: payload.username });

    const task = yield fork(handleIO, socket);

    let action = yield take(`${logout}`);
    yield cancel(task);
    socket.emit('logout');
  }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield fork(flow);
}
```

I have copied the implemenation from here:
https://github.com/kuy/redux-saga-chat-example/blob/master/src/client/sagas.js

The problem is that the while true is totally flooding WebSocket connection. It connects and connects and floods and crash the app.

So here I'm looking for some hints; obviously, there is something I didn't understand about sagas or generator function (or both).

Why could the above chat implementation work without flooding the WebSocket connect and why would my implementation fail and try to connect constantly?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what happens following your code:

```
run this forever
  waits for a "login" action (pauses the generator and the while loop)
  calling connect (does not pause the generator)
  emitting "login" via the socket (does not stop the generator)
  forking handleIO (does not pause the generator)
  waits for a "logout" action (pauses the generator and the while loop)
  canceling what handleIO is doing (does not pause the generator)
  emitting "logout" via the socket (does not pause the generator)
```

Here're couple of hints:

- Isn't it like you have to wait to see if the `connect` actually connects to the socket server. Or maybe it returns a promise?
- Do you have something that dispatches `logout` action. I'm asking because this (together with `login`) is the only one thing that makes the while loop running again and again.
- Are you sure that you are running the `rootSaga` only once?

P.S.
`${login}` may be written simply as `'login'`